# problems connecting to mysql 5.7.9 database with utf8mb4

Tags: python, mysql, database, character-encoding

I have a python-flask podcasting app i wrote at the beginning of the year. The database is configured to use utf8mb4 charset (full utf-8) (and has default collation utf8mb4_bin)

I am using python-mysql-1.2.5 mysql 5.7.9 on mac Yosemite, but my python app hangs when trying to connect to the database. Installed via homebrew. which installs to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/

After a lot of debugging i can see that the hang is occurring at a line in
/Users/xxx/repos/mypodweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py

in the function:

```
import types, _mysql
...
def set_character_set(self, charset):
        """Set the connection character set to charset. The character
        set can only be changed in MySQL-4.1 and newer. If you try
        to change the character set from the current value in an
        older version, NotSupportedError will be raised."""
        if charset == "utf8mb4":
            py_charset = "utf8"
        else:
            py_charset = charset
        if self.character_set_name() != charset:
            try:
                super(Connection, self).set_character_set(charset) #<<<-- here
            except AttributeError:
                if self._server_version < (4, 1):
                    raise NotSupportedError("server is too old to set charset")
                self.query('SET NAMES %s' % charset)
                self.store_result()
        self.string_decoder.charset = py_charset
        self.unicode_literal.charset = py_charset
```

so this references _mysql.set_character_set(charset) which just hangs with no output ...

So it looks as though _mysql.so is the native library binding? I am guessing so...

One thing I noticed is that there is a different version of the mysql library - mysql 5.7.9 has only /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib 
but _mysql.so references libmysqlclient.18.dylib

The library seems to work though as i can see a sleeping connection in mysql after the hang. So there is a connection made and the library then tries to set the character set on it. (the 2nd row).

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db           | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  3 | root | localhost       | NULL         | Query   |    0 | starting | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
|  5 | root | localhost:52486 | mypodweb_dev | Sleep   |    4 |          | NULL                  |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the error happens when I initially try to migrate my DB in i am using alembic to manage migrations. I have also tried canging the default alembic env.py file to use a QueuePool (instead of a NullPool) - the only difference is that i then get 2 sleeping connections to mypodweb_dev in mysql.

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db           | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  4 | root | localhost:53359 | mypodweb_dev | Sleep   |  961 |          | NULL                  |
|  5 | root | localhost:53856 | mypodweb_dev | Sleep   |   19 |          | NULL                  |
|  6 | root | localhost       | NULL         | Query   |    0 | starting | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+----+------+-----------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

I can't find anything at all when I google for this problem. Looking for a fix or workaround that will just get me going as it just my local dev environment and I'm stuck at the starting gate at the mo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-mysql-1.2.5` only supports MySQL up to 5.5